# What is the difference bwteen tasks.named and tasks.getByName

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

When configuring a task in Gradle Kotlin Script, in Spring docs, it always uses `tasks.getByName` to get the task domain object and change it.

And I noticed some other docs, where uses `tasks.named` which is a `TaskProvider` in the context.

What is the exact difference between these two approaches?

Comment: TaskProviders are part of lazy configuration - do the docs provide enough information for you? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html

Comment: @aSemy For example, what tasks.named can do but getByName can not, and in reverse?

Comment: `tasks.named` returns a TaskProvider, and `getByName` returns a Task. I'm not sure how else I can answer your question… In my opinion the Javadoc and Gradle documentation explains the differences clearly.  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html#sec:how_do_i_reference_a_task